# Greenplum : Getting filenames processed via an external table

Tags: postgresql, greenplum, external-tables

we are processing multiple files using external table. Is there any way I can get the file name being processed in external tables and stored it in database table?

Only workaround I can find is appending the file name to every record in the flat file which isn't ideal when huge dataset and multiple files.

Can anyone help on this

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, the file name is simply never passed from the gpfdist daemon back to Greenplum. So you have to append the file name to each line - you can use gpfdist transformation for doing so

Comment: Thanks, i have appended filename before processing, only problem huge set of files coming from sources and edit those files taking lot of time

Comment: You don't need to do this manually - using gpfdist transformation you can make this work on the flight, i.e. you don't need to edit files. Here is how it might work: https://www.pivotalguru.com/?p=871

Comment: Here is one more link with description: http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4340/admin_guide/load/topics/g-write-the-gpfdist-configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this as well, here's my solution. Please note I'm not an expert in linux, so there may be a one liner solution.

So I wanted to add a filename column in front of my records.

That can be done in sed, I've created a transform.sh file, with the following content:

```
#/bin/sh
filename=$1
#echo $filename >> transform.txt
sed -e "s|^|$filename\v|" $filename
```

Please note that I was using vertical tab as a delimiter, \v. Also in the filename you could have / hence using | . In order to have the value of $filename we have to use double quites for sed.

Test it, it looks good.

```
 ./transform.sh countersamples-2016-03-02--11-51-10.csv
countersamples-2016-03-02--11-51-10.csv
                                       timestamp
                                                machine
                                                       category
                                                               instance
                                                                       name
                                                                           value
countersamples-2016-03-02--11-51-10.csv
                                       2016-03-02 11:51:10.064
                                                              DESKTOP-4PLQKVL
                                                                             Memory

                                                                                   % Committed Bytes In Use
                                                                                                           74.8485488891602
```

This part is done, lets continue with gpfdist. We need a yaml file that can be passed to gpfdist, I named this transform.yaml
Content:

```
---
VERSION: 1.0.0.1
TRANSFORMATIONS:
  add_filename:
     TYPE: input
     CONTENT: data
     COMMAND: /bin/bash transform.sh %filename%
```

Please note that we have the %filename% value here. It seems that gpfdist prefilters the files that needs to be handled, and passes them 1 by 1 to our transform.

Lets fire up gpfdist:

```
gpfdist -c transform.yaml -v
```

Now go into greenplum and create an external table such as:

```
CREATE READABLE EXTERNAL TABLE "ext_transform"
(
    "filename" text,
  "timestamp" timestamp without time zone  ,
  "machine" text  ,
  "category" text  ,
  "instance" text  ,
  "name" text  ,
  "value" double precision 
) 
  LOCATION ('gpfdist://localhost:8080/*/countersamples*.csv#transform=add_filename') 
 FORMAT 'TEXT' 
 ( HEADER DELIMITER '\013' NULL AS '\\N' ESCAPE AS '\\' )
```

And when we select data from it:

```
select * from "ext_transform";
```

We see:
[image: result in greenplum]

I've created 2 folders to see how it reacts if the files are not in the same folder as the transform. This way I can distinguish between the 2 files, even if their data is identical.

Comment: Thanks for replying, it is helpful